# How can I show fraction number use Konva.Text

Tags: konvajs

I want to show a  fraction number (e.g. 2¼) in canvas using Konva.Text?

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that it's always good to add more details to your question, plus what you've tried so far with code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just that Unicode as `text`:

```
const shape = new Konva.Text({
  x: 10,
  y: 10,
  text: '2¼',
});
layer.add(shape);
```

Or you can make your own solution. Basically, it is just two numbers with a line.

Comment: Thank you for repy! ¼ is only a specail number,I mean to show fraction number (inch) use html tag "sup" and "sub", <sup>6</sup> &frasl; <sub>9</sub>,it's there any way do just like fabric's method text.setSuperscript(begin,end) and setSubscript(begin,end) ?Or Konva.Text just support html tag will be ok!

Comment: `Konva` doesn't support HTML and it doesn't have similar to fabric methods.